# BTreeMap with comparison function

Tags: rust

I would like to create `BTreeMap` in Rust but to compare my keys I need another data structure which I store in a variable. Unfortunately it seems, that the traits in Rust can't be defined locally and my `Ord` implementation can't depend on local variables.

Does it mean that I have to reimplement whole `BTreeMap` to take lambdas?

Comment: Just a couple of weeks ago I published the [copse](https://crates.io/crates/copse) crate for this very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not optimal (because of the extra data/pointer you have to store and could mess up) you could store the local variable (or depending on size & usecase a reference to it) alongside your values:

```rust
use std::cmp::{PartialOrd, Ord, Ordering};
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn main() {
    dbg!(by_distance_from(-5));
}

fn by_distance_from(x: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let v = vec![-5, 0, 1, 3, 10];
    struct Comp<'a> {
        cmp: &'a Cmp,
        v: i32,
    }
    struct Cmp {
        x: i32,
    }
    let cmp = Cmp { x };
    impl PartialOrd for Comp<'_> {
        fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
            self.v.abs_diff(self.cmp.x).partial_cmp(&other.v.abs_diff(other.cmp.x))
        }
    }
    impl Ord for Comp<'_> {
        fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
            self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
        }
    }
    impl PartialEq for Comp<'_> {
        fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
            self.v == other.v
        }
    }
    impl Eq for Comp<'_> {}
    let s: BTreeSet<_> = v.into_iter().map(|v| Comp {
        cmp: &cmp,
        v,
    }).collect();
    s.into_iter().map(|Comp { v, ..}| v).collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=284b72e115c7caf4690e2e811d2f1acf)